# how to remove a part of a string

Tags: java, string

Given two strings, base and remove, return a version of the base string where all instances of the remove string have been removed (not case sensitive). You may assume that the remove string is of length 1 or more. Remove only non-overlapping instances, so with "xxx" removing "xx" leaves "x".

```
withoutString("Hello there", "llo") → "He there"
withoutString("Hello there", "e") → "Hllo thr"
withoutString("Hello there", "x") → "Hello there"
```

Why can't I use this code:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove)
{
    base.replace(remove, "");
    return base;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get, why people up voting this question.. :P

Answer (score 8):

`base.replace` doesn't change the original `String` instance, since `String` is an immutable class. Therefore, you must return the output of `replace`, which is a new `String`.

```
      public String withoutString(String base, String remove) 
      {
          return base.replace(remove,"");
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

`String#replace()` returns a new string, doesn't change the one it is invoked on, since strings are immutable. Use this in your code:

`base = base.replace(remove, "")`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
   //base.replace(remove,"");//<-- base is not updated, instead a new string is builded
   return base.replace(remove,"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
          return base.replace(remove,"");
      }
```

For **Input :**

```
base=Hello World   
remove=llo
```

**Output :**

```
He World
```

For more on such `string` operations visit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0) library has already implemented this method,you don't need to write again.

Code :

```
 return StringUtils.remove(base, remove);
```